# perl return all elements in array individually from subroutine

Tags: perl, return, element, subroutine

total perl noob here.

I'm trying to write a program that will:

1. process several groups of words (one array=one group) in a subroutine
2. return the results to one gigantic array
3. modify the gigantic array later in the program

Currently, my gigantic array is an array of arrays, and it's a hassle to work with. Is there any way I can return the results as individual elements, instead of an array reference? The smaller arrays are of variable lengths.

So say after processing my array results are this:

```
@array=["A", "B", "C", "D"];
```

I'd like:

```
@giganticarray=["array1stuff", "etc", "A", "B", "C", "D", "array3stuff", "etc"];
```

I tried this:

```
foreach (@array){
        return $_;
}
```

and this

```
for (my $n=scalar (@array); $n>0; $n--) {
        return $array[$n];
}
```

I can't find any information on the web, but it may be because I'm looking for the wrong thing. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you realize that `@array = [ "a", "b" ]` assigns an array reference to `@array`? Is that intentional? Are you using -w or `use warnings;`? `@array = ( @ar1, @ar2, @ar3 );` will give you one flat array with the contents of the other 3. Have you read the Camel book?

Comment: Can you post some of your actual code? Your explanation of it is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *flatten* an array of arrays, you need just

```
@giganticarray = map { ref $_ ? @$_ : $_ } @giganticarray
```

but it would be much cleaner if you generated the array the way you want it in the first place. Show us your code and we can show you how